# Can you develop a parental control app in flutter?

Tags: flutter

Can you develop a parental control app in flutter? To disallow access to a website

Answer (score 0):

I think this is impossible or it is a bad choice. Function which you describes needs an access to the OS functions and APIs but this is impossible from Flutter by itself.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Flutter Docs

https://docs.flutter.dev/platform-integration/platform-channels

Screen Time API docs

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/screentime
https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/683281

Anecdote

https://medium.com/novumlogic/kidsecure-parental-control-mobile-app-in-flutter-part-1-595db580ccb7

It's difficult to find tutorials or much information on writing platform specific coded features but I'm working on a flutter app right now utilizing family controls/screen time API for disallowing access to social media apps for certain periods of time.